# Transferring values of programmatically created checkboxes into the next Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, checkbox, spinner, getvalue

In my `Activity_fruits` there is a spinner with fruit names like "Apple, Pineapple, ..., etc.).  When the user selects one of the items in the spinner, a series of check boxes is generated.

These checkboxes are names of dishes that come from my `Dishes.java` class.  Every different **fruit** selected by the user from the spinner will create different **dish** checkboxes depending on which dishes corresponds to which fruit.

My question is:  **how do I pass the value/text of these generated check boxes into my next activity** `Activity_checkout` when they are selected/checked by the user?

I have code below that seems to run fine BUT the value/text of the checked checkboxes (contained in the `test[0]` intent) isn't being transferred to the next activity.

Below is my views and controls declarations:

public class Activity_fruits extends Activity {

```
    // Instantiate Fruits class
    private Fruits fruits = new Fruits();
    private Dish dish = new Dish();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fruits);

        final String passToNextActivity = getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedDish");

    final String fruitStr = spnFruits.getSelectedItem().toString();
    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    final int count = ll.getChildCount();
    final String[] test = {""};
...
```

And below is how I programmatically generated check boxes for dishes (grabbed from my Dish.java class).  There is no xml layout for my CheckBoxes:

```
 // Create different dish checkboxes for each food selection in the spinner
        spnFruits.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String fruitStr = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                TextView txtRestaurant = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFruits);

                //This TextView is just to confirm the fruit that the user selected
                txtFruit.setText("You selected the Fruit: " + fruitStr);

                final List<String> listFruits = fruits.getFruits(fruitStr);

                // Clears the layout everytime the user selects another fruit from the spinner
                ll.removeAllViews();

                for (int j = 0; j < listFruits.size(); j++) {
                    final CheckBox cbDishes = new CheckBox(Activity_fruits.this);
                    cbDishes.setText(listFruits.get(j));
                    cbDishes.setTag(listFruits);

                    ll.addView(cbDishes);

                    ////////////
                    cbFruits.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                for (int x = 0; x < count; x++) {
                                    View v = ll.getChildAt(x);

                                    if (v instanceof  CheckBox){
                                        test[0] = ((CheckBox) v).getText().toString(); } //My problem:  This code is not storing any string at all
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    ////////////
                }
            }

        });

        /////////////

        Button btnNextActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNextActivity);

        btnNextActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_fruits.this, Activity_checkout.class);
                intent.putExtra("selectedDishes", test[0]); //My Problem:  The test[0] is supposed to contain all user selected check boxes but it doesn't.
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And my next activity `Activity_checkout` is:

```
public class Activity_checkout extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkout);

        final String dishes = getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedDishes");

        TextView txtSelectedDish = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSelectedDish);

        txtSelectedDishs.setText("Your selected dishes are:  " + dishes.toString()); //My Problem:  food.dishes.toString() is not returning a value meaning the checkbox value from Activity_fruits wasn't successfully transferrred over.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The for in your OnClickListener is not executed because count is probably 0 since it is initialized right after inflating ll

```
 count = ll.getChildCount();
```

before any checkboxes have been added.
You should use **ll.getChildCount()** directly in the clicklistener or initialize count and set the listeners after the for loop which creates the checkboxes.